# $\lg_{2} \left( \prod\limits_{a=1}^{2015} \prod\limits_{b=1}^{2015} (1 + e^{\frac{2\pi iab}{2015}}) \right)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, logarithms

> How can this problem be solved?
>
> $$
> \lg_{2} \left( \prod\limits_{a=1}^{2015} \prod\limits_{b=1}^{2015}  (1 + e^{\frac{2\pi iab}{2015}})  \right)
> $$

Comment: By solved you mean evaluated? Let me guess... this is another Putnam problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}\prod_{a=1}^{2015}\prod_{b=1}^{2015}\left(1+e^{\frac{2\pi i a b}{2015}}\right)=&\prod_{d\mid 2015}\prod_{\substack{1≤a≤2015\\ \space (2015,a)=d}}\prod_{b=1}^{2015}\left(1+e^{\frac{2\pi i a b}{2015}}\right)\\=&
\prod_{d\mid 2015}\prod_{\substack{1≤a≤2015\\ \space (2015,a)=d}}2^d\\=&\prod_{d\mid 2015}2^{d\varphi\left(\frac{2015}{d}\right)}
\end{align*}$$
Thus, the logarithm evaluates at:
$$
\lg_2\left(\prod_{d\mid 2015}2^{d\varphi\left(\frac{2015}{d}\right)}\right)=\sum_{d\mid 2015}d\varphi\left(\frac{2015}{d}\right)=13725
$$
This can be calculated by hand. Furthermore, as r9m pointed out, this sum is multiplicative. By observing that
$$
\sum_{d\mid p^k}d\varphi\left(\frac{p^k}{d}\right)=p^{k-1}((k+1)p-k)
$$
we obtain
$$
\sum_{d\mid 2015}d\varphi\left(\frac{2015}{d}\right)=(2\cdot5-1)(2\cdot13-1)(2\cdot 31 -1)=13725
$$

**Explanation:**

If $(2015,a)=d$, we can see that 
$$
\prod_{b=1}^{2015}\left(1+e^{\frac{2\pi i a b}{2015}}\right)=\left[\prod_{b=1}^{\frac{2015}{d}}\left(1+\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i b}{\frac{2015}{d}}\right)\right)\right]^d
$$
By factoring the polynomial $$x^n-1=\prod_{b=1}^{n}\left(x-e^{\frac{2\pi i b}{n}}\right)$$we can see that $$(-1)^n-1=\prod_{b=1}^{n}\left(-1-e^{\frac{2\pi i b}{n}}\right)=(-1)^n\prod_{b=1}^{n}\left(1+e^{\frac{2\pi i b}{n}}\right)$$and thus $$\prod_{b=1}^{n}\left(1+e^{\frac{2\pi i b}{n}}\right)=1-(-1)^n$$Since every divisor of $2015$ is odd, we obtain
$$
\left[\prod_{b=1}^{\frac{2015}{d}}\left(1+\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i b}{\frac{2015}{d}}\right)\right)\right]^d=2^d
$$
Leading to the result described above.

Comment: (+1) Nice! When you say 'calculated by hand' do you have any specific idea/way in mind?

Comment: @r9m Well, nothing intelligent, but as $2015=5*13*31$ has only $8$ divisors, it takes not to long to calculate it using $\varphi(n)=n\cdot\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$. And thanks for the edit! :)

Comment: $\sum\limits_{d | n} d\varphi (n/d)$ is convolution of two multiplicative functions, hence it's multiplicative as well. :)